# How to send info as Json data to server without Post method or any form

Tags: javascript, json

I have been given I task to work with Json to send data to server without actually using the "form" or "Post", below are the conversations between me and my senior:

Senior:

> send only the data to the server without submitting the form
>   in javascript

```
 myJsonObject.Username = document.getElementById('txtUsername').value;
```

> this will be done when Save button click
>   in such situation, we don't use form element
>   we don't use submit button
>   just a simple button for save

```
 onclick="saveUser()"
 function saveUser(){
 var userInfoJson = { };
 userInfoJson.Username = document.getElementById('txtUsername').value;
```

> ...and so on
>   just play around with json

Me:

```
<form name="form" method="post" onsubmit="saveUser()">
```

> will it look like this?

Senior:

> ** don't use form tag
>   don't use submit button

Me

```
:
one more thing will it have <input type="text"> ?
```

Senior:

```
not sure what u mean
u can use any kind of html, i don't mind
you need to show me some coding of json and that happens in .JS file
 or in <script type="text\javascript" tag
html can be used to integrate ur user input
i don't mind u use any kind of html whether beautiful or not
I MEAN JSON here in this thread
I wan't json... json, json, json
don't bring the whole world here... talk about json
json only
```

**So how one can do it without form?**

Comment: Sending data to the server in JSON format implies usage of either POST or PUT. In rare cases - DELETE. So I'm not sure what your senior meant by "without using post". As for storing values - you don't need `form` tag to use `input` tags (to get the data from), but in that case I'm not sure about semantical correctness of the page.

Comment: Where does "senior" say not to "post". He says not to use a form tag or submit button.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand the reason for not using a form or submit button it seems counter intuitive and is probably not valid markup.

However for this to work you can just bind to a normal button...

http://jsfiddle.net/Labdr6pw/

```
<input type="text" id="txtUsername" name="username" />
<button id="submitButton" type="button">Save</button>
```

```
var submitButton = document.getElementById('submitButton'),
    usernameInput = document.getElementById('txtUsername'),
    userInfoJson = {};

userInfoJson.Username = usernameInput.value;

submitButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest(); 

    request.open("POST", "webservice", true);
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState != 4 || request.status != 200) return; 
        console.log(request.responseText);
    };
    request.send(JSON.stringify(userInfoJson));
});
```

Comment: Where can i see the result Json? i mean inside a div?

Comment: What do you mean? The response back from the server is in `console.log(request.responseText)` do you mean you just want to display `userInfoJson` when you click save and not actually send to any server?